# XMPP HTTP Binding

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, instant-messaging, agsxmpp

According to the wiki, XMPP could use HTTP in two ways: one is polling and other one is binding. This binding model of notification is more efficient than polling, where many of the polls return no new data.

Can anybody explain to me,

- how it work and
- how to use the http-bind url (http://jabber.org:5280/) when we developing the client application using agsXmpp library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[XEP-0206](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0206.html) and [XEP-0124](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0124.html) specify Bidirectional-streams Over Synchronous HTTP (BOSH), which is the protocol for the binding approach.  I don't think agsXmpp supports BOSH, but their newer version ([Matrix](http://www.ag-software.de/matrix-xmpp-sdk/)) does, as well as [Jabber-Net](http://code.google.com/p/jabber-net/).

Comment: yes, Thanks Joe. Matrix is a commercial one. I'm looking for an open source library.